# invariant subspaces endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm wondering about invariant subspaces.
If we have an endomorphism $f$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$ such as its matrix in canonical basis is

\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 0 \\
   -1 & 2 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}

and $V=Vect{(1,1,1)}$, $Z=Vect((1,0,0),(0,1,-1))$

Is $V$ invariant by $f$ ? And how to prove $Z$ is invariant by $f$ ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The subspace $V$ is  an invariant of $f $ if $f (V)\subseteq V $. The same definition follows for the subspace generated by the vectors in $Z $. To show this you need to apply the matrix to an arbitrary vector in $V $ and show that it is a multiple of $(1, 1, 1) $ (or find a counterexample). Hint: Try calculating $f ((1, 1, 1))$ and see if its image is in $V $.

Similarly for the subspace $Z$ you can do this to the generating set of vectors individually (since it is a linear transformation $f (a+b)=f (a)+f (b) $) and show that the sum of their images is still in $Z $ for the arbitrary vectors $(a,0,0)$ and $(0,b,-b)$.

Comment: Feel free to ask for further clarification.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that there's an equal sign in $f(V) = V$. By your definition, the kernel of a matrix isn't an invariant subspace.

Comment: Whoops thanks for catching that mistake.